# Dart/Flutter: Firebase and Firestore wait for async for loop to complete before continuing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to submit images to Firebase storage, and then also submit the links to the images to the new record that I am "linking" the images to.

My issue is that if I add image(s) to the data, it seems that the upload makes the rest of the firebase activity not happen (it doesn't make sense to me).

So essentially when I click the FAB then it's supposed to submit the data.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.send),

          // SUBMIT THE DATA
          onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              // Show the modal spinner until submit is complete
              showSpinner = true;
            });

            // upload images
            List<StorageReference> fileRefs = [];
            for (var image in imageFiles) {
              fileRefs.add(await uploadPic(context, image));
            }

      // When there are images in the imageFiles array then the below part doesn't run
      // but if no images was selected it runs fine, if images are selected they get uploaded
      // to firebase storage, but no record gets added. :(

            _firestore.collection('InspectionPoints').add({
              'project': selectedProject,
              // some other fields
              'user': loggedInUser.email,
              'photoIds': fileRefs.length == 0 ? [] : fileRefs,
              'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
              //'photoIds' : imageFiles;
            });
           
            setState(() {
              // <---------------  this still runs
              clearForm();
              showSpinner = false;
            });
          } // onPressed
          ),
```

I also now tried to put the getting the file refs into an async formula, but it also doesn't work:

```
            // upload images
            List<StorageReference> fileRefs = await getFileRefs(context);
```

And the new function:

```
  Future<List<StorageReference>> getFileRefs(BuildContext context) async {
    List<StorageReference> fileRefs = [];
    for (var image in imageFiles) {
      fileRefs.add(await uploadPic(context, image));
    }
    return fileRefs;
  }
```

**Edit**: My Actual uploading code:

```
  Future<StorageReference> uploadPic(BuildContext context, File image) async {
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(basename(image.path));
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    setState(() {
      print('File: ${image.path} uploaded to the cloud');
      showInSnackBar('File: ${image.path} uploaded to the cloud');
    });
    return taskSnapshot.ref;
  }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem right and look dirty, just explain exactly what you want to do, So I can help

Comment: Where is `uploadPics` defined?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I've added the upload code, but that's not where (I think) the issue lies.  @samezedi my issue is that it seems like uploading images makes the `_firebase.collection('InspectionPoints').add(...)` code not execute (or maybe it executes, but it never arrives at the firestore).

Answer (score 0):

To upload an image to Firebase Storage, you can use the code below.

```
Future upLoadImage(_providedFile, String folderName, String imageName) async{
   //_providedFile -> FILE THAT CONTAINS IMAGE
   //folderName -> FOLDER NAME IN FIREBASE STORAGE
   //imageName -> NAME OF THE IMAGE THAT WILL BE SAVED ON FIREBASE STORAGE

  //FILE UPLOAD LOCATION
  //IF YOU DON'T WANT TO ADD IMAGE IN A FOLDER JUST REMOVE
  //".child(folderName)" from the line  
  StorageReference reference = firebasestorage.ref().child(folderName).child('$imageName.jpg');

  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_providedFile);  await 

  uploadTask.onComplete;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I've made an edit to show my upload code.  The issue isn't that the storage isn't getting the image, it's that the other firebase code doesn't actually execute if the storage code is executing.  Almost like it cancels the rest of the code.  If I am not uploading an image then the normal firebase code runs fine.

Comment: Ok, so i can't find any error in the FAB onpressed. So, try to write the Database Entry code before the Storage(or the Image Upload) code.

Comment: Then I don't have the image references yet... I want to somehow connect the image references to the DB entry.  Maybe I can edit it afterwards, I just need the reference to what I just added... does .add leave a reference?

Comment: **Document is being created in your Database without the reference(`photoIds` in your case)** or the **Document is not getting created in your Database?**

Comment: If I don't add images, then this code: `_firebase.collection('InspectionPoints').add(...)` executes, and I get a new firebase entry in the InspectionPoints collection with the fields: project, user, timestamp, and an empty array `[]` in pphotoIds.  If I add images, then I get all the new images uploaded into the my firebase store, but I don't get a new firebase entry in InspectionPoints with any of the details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save the type `StorageReference` to firebase cloud, and due to that type failing to submit the whole submit fails, but because the images are uploaded separately from the data entry, they are already there by the time the data entry fails to submit.

The fix was to convert the `StorageReference` to string via the `.path` property.